# dropbox about production status

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am an android developer and I am using dropbox api in my project.

I did register my app and I did get the api key and secret. I am looking for production status information. From what I read this gives you the ability to use the key/passwd for more than 100 users.

Where can I find information about what is this production status and how much does this cost?

Can someone help me? SO far I haven t find anything on the internet.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Production Status is the status of Your app. This means, You don´t have to buy anything, go to the DropBox developer console where You had registered Your app and select "App Console". Here You should be able to change the status of Your app. You have to fill out some questions to change your status. It could need some time before status is changed, sometimes about 24 hours.

Before Your status is not in "Production", Your users cannot use the dropBox feature.

Comment: Is there an android application that includes login username+password + upload + download files/pictures? I found https://github.com/mlamina/DropboxSDK-for-Android but DropBoxSample is not working. When trying to login it return Login Failed. Unsuccessful login though I did put a consumer_key and secret

Comment: the DropBox developer site contains a good example. The example You found on github is 2 years old, maybe at this time, the drobBox example was not good. But now, this contains enough to know where to start at:  https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/setup#android

Comment: 24 hours would be great...but it's not my case...My app has "In Review" status (Dropbox App Console) for almost 4 days now.

Comment: The You should contact dropbox. I had also some problems in the past and I get very fast help from them. It was fixed in just two hours...

Answer (score 0):

If you are app exceeded 50 dropbox users  you have to apply for production status.
Also as a developer  they will give 500 Dropbox user before your app will be freezed if you don't apply for production status.